# calculate exchange price depending on user choice from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting data with php from database, converting to js array using json_encode. All good. But there are 4 indexes in array, and i'm trying to use specific index depending on user choice in  in html. I want to do this with jquery/js. Look at code for deeper explanation!

jsfiddle: EDIT: updated syntax in jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqd9vjnh/2/

html

```
    <label for="amount"><h3><i class="fa fa-database">&nbsp;Amount</i></h3></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" name="gpamount" required>

<select class="form-control" name="goldtype" style="margin-top:30px; width: 70%;" id="goldtype">
                                            <option value="x">Val1</option>
                                            <option value="y">Val2</option>
                                            <option value="z">Val3</option>
                                        </select>

                        <label for="price"><h3><i class="fa fa-database">&nbsp;Price</i></h3></label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" >
```

js/jquery

```
var amount = $('#amount'),
  goldtype = $('#goldtype'),
  exchange = ["0.5", "1.5", "3.5", "$"] //I will set static array here. //<?php echo json_encode($exchangeRates);?>,
price = $('#price');

var choice = goldtype.val();
if (choice = x) {
  goldtype = exchange[0];
}
if (choice = y) {
  goldtype = exchange[1];
}
if (choice = z) {
  goldtype = exchange[2];
}

amount.add(goldtype).on('change input', function() {
  price.val(function() {
    return (amount.val() * goldtype.val().toFixed(2) + '')
  })
});
```

Comment: *"Look at code for deeper explanation"* . No. Provide a proper explanation of what you expect this code to do. Broken code isn't a substitute for a proper explanation. Demo is broken due to errors thrown and code in question is hard to read to lack of formatting

Comment: ah sorry i need help with logic and syntax perhaps.. thanks

Comment: `x`, `y`, and `z` should be in quotes, and the comparisons in the if statements should be with `===`, not with `=` (which does an assignment). You would set the value of the `goldtype` field with `goldtype.val(exchange[0])`, not with `=`.

Comment: There is so much wrong here I suggest you get a basic set of events working first without the array and then integrate the array into calculation after. in addition to what @nnnnnn says you are overwriting `goldtype` variable and not doing value checks inside an event handler

Comment: i fixed some syntay on jsfiddle tysm

Comment: can you please explain what output you want if user selects val1 and what for val2 selection ??

Comment: val1  output 0.5, val 2 output 1.5, val 3 output 3.5 so val 1 = array[0], val 2 array[1] val 3 array[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try being more explicit when asking for help because not only does it save other people time, but it also lowers the chance of your question being downvoted and dismissed.
I've come up with something that I **THINK** should be the answer to your problem, and if not please say so.

The following code finds out which of the options was chosen and multiplies the amount with the exchange value of the same index.

```
goldtype.change(function () {
    var exchangeIndex = $("select[name='goldtype'] option:selected").index()
    price.val(amount.val() * exchange[exchangeIndex]);
})
```

I also threw in a piece of code that changes your options according to the exchange array when you first click the array (hope that helps).

You can find the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/pghiran/pen/QEvRjW).

Comment: this is nice, but you based it on number. I am storing number in array (database) and i don't want to display integer in dropdown, but as String. And then depending what string was choosen take integer from array.

Comment: Nwm you're script works on array, but it doesn't work on array from php! thanks